# SQL: reverse groupby : EDIT

Tags: sql, group-by, eloquent

Is there a build in function in sql, to reverse the order in which the groupby works? I try to groupby a certain key but i would like to have the last inserted record returned and not the first inserted record.

Changing the order with orderby does not affect this behaviour.

Thanx in advance!

EDIT:

this is the sample data:

```
id|value
-----
1 | A
2 | B
3 | B
4 | C
```

as return i want

```
1 | A
3 | B
4 | C
```

not

```
1 | A
2 | B
4 | C
```

when using group by id don't get the result i want.

Comment: Please show us some sample data which illustrates your question.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.  The question is unclear to me and sample data would help clarify.  Seems to me you want a max on the date or you want to select max(Inserted), ID group by ID then join back to the base set to get the most recent record of each group?

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't return "sample" records.  You should have proper aggregation functions to get the value that you intend.

Comment: The LAG function will return the last row from a query if that is what you are truly asking for, but your question is very unclear.

Comment: GROUP BY w/o aggregation really doesn't make sense.   you have no aggregation at this time. The only time you really need a group by is when you're using min/max/avg etc...  If you have duplicate records to get rid of I'd use distinct to make the meaning plain.

Answer (score 1):

Question here is how are you identifying `last inserted row`. Based on your example, it looks like based on `id`. If `id` is auto generated, or a sequence then you can definitely do this.

```
select max(id),value
from your_table
group by value
```

Ideally in a table design, people uses a date column which holds the time a particular record was inserted, so it is easy to order by that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Max() as your aggregate function for your `id`:

```
SELECT max(id), value FROM <table> GROUP BY value;
```

This will return:

```
1 | A
3 | B
4 | C
```

As for `eloquent`, I've not used it but I think it would look like:

```
$myData = DB::table('yourtable')
                 ->select('value', DB::raw('max(id) as maxid'))
                 ->groupBy('value')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: How can i convert this to 'eloquent' ?